# Debugging failure to hash on the SQL side

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to get hashing to work for passwords. They're currently unsalted for debugging purposes.

Currently the hashing algorithm I use is `SHA1`.

My table (called `Users`) consists of:

- `[phone] varchar(32)`
- `[password] binary(20)`

To populate my database, I use this query:

```
DELETE FROM Users

INSERT INTO Users (phone, password)
VALUES ('0526487612', HASHBYTES(SHA1, 'admin123'))
```

When I log in, I do this:

```
command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@UName AND password=HASHBYTES('SHA1', @PWord)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PWord", password);

reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    // ...
}
```

When I try to log in (with the username `0526487612` and the password `admin123`), it never enters the `if(...)` (meaning the reader doesn't find any rows matching the query).

Everything works if I don't hash the password - meaning the issue isn't elsewhere.

I tried using a different hashing algorithm (`SHA2_256`) and changing the SQL Server data type accordingly (`binary(32)`), but the result is the same.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014; and I have no idea how to debug this further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal bet is that when you run your query directly from SQL Server Management Studio and run following statement:

```
DELETE FROM Users;
INSERT INTO Users (phone, password)
VALUES ('0526487612', HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'admin123'));
```

Your password (`admin123`) is a `VARCHAR`. Now when you execute your code, it's not executed just like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@UName AND password=HASHBYTES('SHA1', @PWord);
```

Instead, it executes this statement (your parameter is sent as `NVARCHAR`):

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', @p1)'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
```

Casting `@p1` (your password) as `VARCHAR` solves the issue.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', CAST(@p1 AS VARCHAR(30)))'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
```

Running this proves that `NVARCHAR` outputs different binary:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'admin123') AS VarcharSHA1
    , HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'admin123') AS nVarcharSHA1;
```

Result:

```
VarcharSHA1                                 nVarcharSHA1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0xF865B53623B121FD34EE5426C792E5C33AF8C227  0xB7BC3A1B04D9E165C6762B0A1CDE5226DF5B6A6A
```

Full example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Users', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Users;

CREATE TABLE Users
(
    [phone] VARCHAR(30)
    , [password] BINARY(20)
);

INSERT INTO Users ([phone], [password])
VALUES ('0526487612', HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'admin123'));

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', @p1)'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
-- Doesn't bring result back

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', CAST(@p1 AS VARCHAR(30)))'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
-- Brings results back

TRUNCATE TABLE Users;
INSERT INTO Users ([phone], [password])
VALUES ('0526487612', HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'admin123'));
                                  --    ^
                                  --    |
                                  -- Notice this

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', @p1)'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
-- Brings results back

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phone=@p0 AND password=HASHBYTES(''SHA1'', CAST(@p1 AS VARCHAR(30)))'
    , N'@p0 NVARCHAR(100), @p1 NVARCHAR(100)'
    , @p0 = N'0526487612'
    , @p1 = N'admin123';
-- Doesn't bring result back
```

So I've pointed out the problem, now it's up to you how to fix it. Either always cast your password as `VARCHAR` or just use unicode equivalent when hashing it.

#### Update

So apparently you don't have so insert your password and hash it as `NVARCHAR`, but you have to slightly modify your c# code to pass in value data type you want, not data type ADO.NET selects by itself. Please read this article: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for more information.

Based on that, you could update your code like that and it should work just fine:

```
command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"
  SELECT *
  FROM Users
  WHERE phone = @UName
    AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @PWord)";

//Add parameters like that and it will pass in correct data type
command.Parameters.Add("@UName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = username;
command.Parameters.Add("@PWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = password;

//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", username);
//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PWord", password);

reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Suppose I convert what `HASHBYTES` returns to a `NVARCHAR` - should I also change the table column's data type to `NVARCHAR`? If so, how big should it be? (How many binaries are in a nvarchar?)

Comment: @Ivan perhaps you misunderstood me. Everything is fine with your table structure. The issue is that when you insert record into database you're hashing `admin123` as VARCHAR and in when you execute your code you're hashing it as NVARCHAR datatype. Even though input is the same, their data types differ and hashbytes output different values. That's why it you cannot login.

Comment: So when inserting I should convert `'admin123'` to `nvarchar`. Correct?

Comment: @Ivan that's correct. Insert `N'admin123'` instead of  `'admin123'`. N before quote indicates that following text is going to be NVARCHAR

Comment: I'll check if that solves it once i'm at my workstation.

Comment: @Ivan that's totally fine. Let me know if this was the actual issue. :-)

Comment: @IvanRubinson I've updated my answer with another possible approach and it seems to be much better. Check it out! :)